# why can't i programmatically copy a locked .mdb but i can copy it through explorer?

Tags: ms-access, filesystems, vba, etl

I intended to write a VBA function which would copy a .mdb file if a certain criterion is met.

I hit a roadblock when I realized the `FileCopy` method throws an error if the `.mdb` it is trying to copy/paste has an associated `.ldb` file.

However, I am able to manually copy/paste the `.mdb` through windows explorer.

The `.mdb` i am trying to copy will always be locked, since I have added a reference to it in the DB that is running the filecopy procedure.

**Can someone show me how to force a copy programatically with VBA?** I tried searching but all I found was advice against doing this because of DB corruption etc. BUT this won't be an issue, because none of the DB objects will be manipulated while this procedure is executing.

If anyone is curious, here is my procedure:

```
Function fn_ArchiveMonthEndDB()

    'load INI data
    fn_ReadINI

    Dim asOfDate As Date
    asOfDate = getAsOfDate()
    Dim monthEndDate As Date
    monthEndDate = fn_GetMonthEndDate()


    sSQL = "SELECT CDate(Nz(LastRunDate,'1/1/1990')) as BackupDate FROM tbl_UseStats WHERE ProcessName = 'Archive Backend DB'"
    Dim rs As Recordset
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sSQL)

    Dim dLastBackup As Date
    dLastBackup = rs!BackupDate

    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing

    If (dLastBackup <> monthEndDate) Then

            'determine if it actually is month-end. if yes, then archive the DB.
            If (asOfDate = monthEndDate) Then
                'archive backend DB
                sDir = iBackendArchive & "\" & CStr(Year(monthEndDate)) & CStr(Month(monthEndDate))

                'create dir if it does not exist
                If (Dir(sDir, vbDirectory)) = "" Then
                    MkDir sDir
                End If

                FileCopy iBackendPath & "\ETL_be.mdb", sDir & "\ETL_be.mdb"

            Else
                'if no, do nothing
            End If

    ElseIf (dLastBackup = monthEndDate) Then
        'do nothing, because we already took a backup of the backend DB.
    End If

End Function
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft explains it pretty simply in their [KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/207703).

---

- Create a module and type the following lines in the Declarations section:

```
Option Explicit

Declare Function apiCopyFile Lib "kernel32" Alias "CopyFileA" _
(ByVal lpExistingFileName As String, _
ByVal lpNewFileName As String, _
ByVal bFailIfExists As Long) As Long
```

---

- Type the following procedure:

```
Sub CopyFile(SourceFile As String, DestFile As String)
'---------------------------------------------------------------
' PURPOSE: Copy a file on disk from one location to another.
' ACCEPTS: The name of the source file and destination file.
' RETURNS: Nothing
'---------------------------------------------------------------
  Dim Result As Long
   If Dir(SourceFile) = "" Then
      MsgBox Chr(34) & SourceFile & Chr(34) & _
         " is not valid file name."
   Else
      Result = apiCopyFile(SourceFile, DestFile, False)
   End If
End Sub
```

---

- To test this procedure, type the following line in the Immediate window, and then press ENTER:

```
CopyFile "<path to Northwind.mdb>", "C:\Northwind.mdb"
```